# How to center multiple buttons horizontally in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am creating multiple buttons programmatically. For an example, if I am creating two buttons with defined spacing among buttons, I want to center these two buttons horizontally in the view controller. How can I do this with swift?

Comment: Look into UIStackView.

Answer (score 2):

`UIStackView` is what you're looking for.

**Example**

Declare `btn1`, `btn2` first, then put them into a `UIStackView`.

```
lazy var horizontalStackView: UIStackView = {
    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
        btn1,
        btn2
        ])
    sv.axis = .horizontal
    sv.spacing = 8
    return sv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.addSubview(horizontalStackView)
    // Then set up its constraint of horizontalStackView
    horizontalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    horizontalStackView.topAnchor...
}
```

At last, you just need to anchor the `horizontalStackView` like a normal `UIView` to where you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UIStackView` with `horizontal` axis property, add the buttons inside the `UIStackView` and add constraints on stackView to center in the view.

Here is the simple example of centering two buttons equally at the bottom of the screen, 8 points above safeAreaLayout guides.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var button1: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("Button1", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var button2: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.setTitle("Button2", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var horizontalStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1, button2])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 8
        return stackView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(horizontalStackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            horizontalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            horizontalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            horizontalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            horizontalStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor), 
            horizontalStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    }
}
```

here is the view:

[image: botton_center_buttons]

Play around this code in playground and change as per your requirements.